# Get current directory (without full path) in Fish Shell

Tags: prompt, fish

A buddy of mine finally got me to start using Fish Shell and I'm trying to set it up similar to how I had Bash. The `PS1` in my `.bash_profile` listed the current directory I was in, followed by a `>`. It, however, wasn't the absolute path (e.g. `/Users/me/Documents/...` or `~/Documents/...`). If I was in `/Users/me/Documents/projects/Go/project1/`, the prompt would simply say `project1 >`.

Is there a Fish Shell alternative to the `\W` substitution available for Bash? Again, I just want the folder I'm in, not the full path. I know you can use the `echo (pwd)` for all that.

I have looked into the `basename` program, and `echo "${PWD##*/}"`, but these appear to only work in Bash.

Comment: Can't you use `basename` as described in the Fish [doc](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/)?

Comment: @EugeniuRosca I tried `echo (basename)` and I get the following:
`usage: basename string [suffix] basename [-a] [-s suffix] string [...]`

Comment: *I have looked into the `basename` program [...] but these appear to only work in Bash.* `basename` is just a Unix utility; it's not associated to a particular shell, and should work equally well in Bash and Fish.

Comment: @Jubobs, it looks like I simply didn't format it properly. I ended up using `echo (basename $PWD)` and this solved it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Taken from @Jubobs' answer:
`basename` is just a Unix utility; it's not associated to a particular shell, and should work equally well in Bash and Fish.

It appeared I was using `basename` in the wrong context, and without a suffix.

This was solved by using the following:

```
function fish_prompt
    echo (basename $PWD) "><> "
end
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative: fish ships with a function called `prompt_pwd` which displays `/Users/me/Documents/projects/Go/project1/` as `~/D/p/G/project1`

```
function fish_prompt
    echo (prompt_pwd) "><> "
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The complete code of `prompt_pwd.fish` is below. You must put it inside the directory `~/.config/fish/functions/`

```
function prompt_pwd --description "Print the current working directory, shortened to fit the prompt"
    set -q argv[1]
    and switch $argv[1]
        case -h --help
            __fish_print_help prompt_pwd
            return 0
    end

    # This allows overriding fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length from the outside (global or universal) without leaking it
    set -q fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length
    or set -l fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 1

    # Replace $HOME with "~"
    set realhome ~

    # @EDITED by Thiago Andrade
    set tmpdir (basename $PWD)
    set -l tmp (string replace -r '^'"$realhome"'($|/)' '~$1' $tmpdir)
    # ORIGINAL VERSION
    # set -l tmp (string replace -r '^'"$realhome"'($|/)' '~$1' $PWD)

    if [ $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length -eq 0 ]
        echo $tmp
    else
        # Shorten to at most $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length characters per directory
        string replace -ar '(\.?[^/]{'"$fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length"'})[^/]*/' '$1/' $tmp
    end
end
```

Then you'll see something like this

[image]

Comment: This can be replaced by `echo (basename $PWD)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my function in

> ~/.config/fish/functions/prompt_pwd.fish

and this seems to work fine

```
    function prompt_pwd 
        set -q argv[1]
        and switch $argv[1]
            case -h --help
                __fish_print_help prompt_pwd
                return 0
        end

        set -q fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length
        or set -l fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 1
        set ttmp $PWD
        set ttmp (string replace -r '^'$HOME'($|/)' '~$1' $PWD)
        set -l tmp (basename $ttmp)

        if [ $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length -eq 0 ]
            echo $tmp
        else
            string replace -ar '(\.?[^/]{'"$fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length"'})[^/]*/' '$1/' $tmp
        end
    end
```